# UIImageView rounder UIImageView strange cornerRadious

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want a rounded image inside a UIImageView. I subclassed UITableViewCell and added the cornerRadious in awakeFromNib like this:

```
class FriendsCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var friendImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.friendImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.friendImageView.frame.size.width / 2
        self.friendImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

And this is what i get:

[image: this is what i get]

And this is what i expected:

[image: this is what i expect]

The code for filling the tableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FriendsCell
    let user = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Friend
    cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(data: user.photo)
    return cell
}
```

I tried also setting the cornerRadius when filling the tableView here, but i get the same result. I also tried with all the modes of contentMode (AspecFill, ScaleToFill..)
The weird thing is that in another VC i have the same layout and this is not happening.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? I wonder if you frame size is unexpectedly large on load and later corrected? Also perhaps try hard code it temporarily to help isolate these kind of effects.

Comment: yes.. was a AL problem.. ty

Comment: what is you imageview frame size...????

Comment: there must be height and width of "self.friendImageView" same in size

Comment: did you try setting cornerRadius in layoutSubviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact problem like you and I try setting this in the function of viewWillLayoutSubviews(). And then everything is ok! below is my code

```
  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    detailPortImageView.image = detailImage
    detailPortImageView.layer.cornerRadius = detailPortImageView.frame.width / 2
    detailPortImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    detailPortImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    detailPortImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
}
```